# Can you update a Vue Pinia store WITHOUT rendering data changes? Or rather, just rendering one data change?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dom

I am using Vue3 composition with script setup. I am using a pinia store.

I have an SPA where the user gradually alters data, which is stored in a history array.
It is possible to recreate all the users' changes by resetting the page, and running through this history array step by step.

As you run through the history array (for loop), the webpage won't update, as JS is single thread. This recreation takes ~1-2 seconds, and so I would like a progress bar to show the progress through the 'for' loop. But I don't want the rest of the page to update with every change to the store as it's altered by going through the history array (of course, being vue, you normally do want everything to update!).

So what I want to know is; can you make changes that would normally result in a vue DOM update, but wait until a for loop has completed until updating? But whilst in the for loop, update just a progress bar, so you can see that something is happening?

I can get the progress bar to update using

`await sleep(0)`

where

`export function sleep(ms) { return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms)); }`

But of course this updates the whole page, not just the progress bar.

Is this possible?

Comment: The question needs to reflect your case, so it could be specifically addressed, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Just off the top of my head, use temporary store data that isn't bound in ui before commiting changes. As for progress bar, css animation may help for infinite indicator, as it works when main thread is blocked

Comment: Does your replay happen outside of all componets, eg in a module or inside a Pinia store? f so maybe uou could divide your app's components into two branches: <ProgressBar> and <EverythingElse> and then unmount <EverythingElse>, do your replay, then mount it again. Disclaimer: never tried this but just a thought...

Answer (score 0):

If there's a out-of-the-box solution, I'd be interested in it.

I'd do the same thing that Estus Flask mentioned in is comment : use temporary object during the replay loop and update your pinia store with final result only in the end.

Another solution, if it's a simple use-case, would be to do something like : your component gets the computed properties from the pinia store (replay in progress and data to display), but rendering is based on another "data" property. Then put a watcher on the both data from the pinia store to update your local `data` to reflect change in pinia store.

Something like this :

```js
  watch: {
    dataFromPiniaStore: function (v) {
      if (!this.replay) {
        this.dataInsideComponent = this.dataFromPiniaStore
      }
    },
    replay: function (v) {
      if (!v) {
        this.dataInsideComponent = this.dataFromPiniaStore
      }
    }
  }
```

That could do the job.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you can either add a boolean to every single reactive thing to manually turn it off, or structure your code in a very specific way.

To keep the website appearance but remove interactiveness, you could use

`let tempVar = document.getElementById('app').innerHTML`

Then try to unmount the app, or change the innerHTML to '', and then restore it from the tempVar. This will restore the appearance (and css) only, with no interactivity. But then I couldn't remount the app.

The following code DOES do this (you need to change the // to change the functions back to timeouts.
Then, the first timeout changes the HTML to static HTML, and the second timeout restarts Vue. However, (and this does depend on how your project is set up), if using Vite, then this will be the main.js.
And as soon as you try to export the useful bits to use them later, you just get an error about accessing things before initialisation. I think it's close.... but not quite there yet. But maybe about as close as you can get. And it does do what I was trying to do, but only in one place.

Obviously the code isn't the neatest, but you can see what I tried, and it might generate a few ideas.

```
import { ref, nextTick } from 'vue';
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import { createPinia } from 'pinia';
import App from './App.vue';

// Function to initialize the Vue app instance
const initializeVueApp = () => {
  const app = createApp(App);
  app.use(createPinia());
    return app;
};

// Create a ref to hold the app instance
const app = ref(initializeVueApp());

// Function to mount the app
const mountApp = () => {
  app.value.mount('#app');
};

// Function to unmount the app
const unmountApp = () => {
  app.value.unmount();
 app.value = null;
};

// Mount the app immediately
nextTick(() => {
  mountApp();
});

// Remount the app after a timeout
//setTimeout(() => {
export  const unmountBApp = () => {
//function doStuff()  {
  const appElement = document.getElementById('app');
  if (appElement) {
    alert(2)
   // unmountApp(); // Unmount the app
    //appElement.innerHTML = ''; // Clear the inner HTML

    // Mount the app again after clearing
    appElement.innerHTML = ''; // Clear the custom HTML after a delay
    app.value = initializeVueApp(); // Create a new app instance
    mountApp();

  }
}
//  , 13000); // Change this delay as needed


 // setTimeout(() => {
  export  const remountApp = () => {

    //function doStuff()  {
    const appElement = document.getElementById('app');
    if (appElement) {
      alert(1)
      let innerH = appElement.innerHTML;
  unmountApp(); // Unmount the app
  //document.innerHTML = innerH
  appElement.innerHTML = '<p>App is unmounted. Display custom HTML     here.</p>'; // Display custom HTML
  appElement.innerHTML = innerH; // Display custom HTML
   
  //appElement.innerHTML = appElement.innerHTML; // Clear the inner HTML

  // Mount the app again after clearing
  //app.value = initializeVueApp(); // Create a new app instance
  //mountApp();
  
    }
  }
  //  , 3000); // Change this delay as needed
```